# Haskell - Checking in a List of a custom Data type fow Equality

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I have these Data types:

```
data Player = Black | White deriving Show
data Cell = Piece Player Int | Empty deriving Show
type Board = [[Cell]]
```

and this instance:

```
instance Eq Player where
  (==) Black Black = True
  (==) White White = True
  (==) _ _ = False
```

And I would like to find out the amount of current black pieces on the Board.

I do know if i would like to find out the amount of a specific piece on the Board i could do something like this:

```
getSpecificPiece :: Board -> [Player]
getSpecificPiece b = concat (map (filter (== Piece Black 170)) b)
```

How do I look for Pieces of for example the color black if I dont care for the Number ?

> concat (map (filter (== Piece Black _ )) b)

This was a was for example something i tried but didn't work.

Comment: A cute but slightly weird way to do: `countBlackPieces b = sum [1 | r <- b, Piece Black _ <- r]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to add: I'm not entirely sure I answered the correct question; this explains how to *count* the black pieces, but it'd need some slight modification if you want, e. g., a list of black pieces instead.

You could do

```hs
countBlackPieces :: Board -> Int
countBlackPieces = length . filter hasBlackPiece . concat
  where hasBlackPiece (Piece Black _) = True
        hasBlackPiece _               = False
```

or

```hs
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

getPieceColor :: Cell -> Maybe Color
getPieceColor (Piece player _) = Just player
getPieceColor _                = Nothing

countBlackPieces :: Board -> Int
countBlackPieces = length . filter (== Black) . mapMaybe getPieceColor . concat
```

I'd probably write the first one, unless I had another use for `getPieceColor`. You can avoid writing `getPieceColor` by giving the `Player` field of `Cell` a name, but that accessor would be partial (i. e. error out when given `Empty`), which I think is generally considered a bad idea.

You may know this, but in case you don't:  `deriving Eq` for `Player` will result in exactly the `Eq` instance you've written.